# discord.py cog not loading on startup

Tags: discord.py

so, my code looks a little something like this

main.py

```
import (all the required imports are here)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print('----------')
     for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
     if filename.endswith('.py'):
          bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
bot.run('token')
```

music.py

```
class Music(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

     @commands.command()
     async def join(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
     (insert the rest of the commands here)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
     print('------')
def setup(bot): 
     bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
bot.run('token')
```

my directory looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/naSqQ.png

but when i run it, the cog isn't shown to be active..what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you import them in a pythonian way? `from cogs import *` looks and probably performs way better than what you are trying to do.

Comment: use ``@commands.Cog.listener()`` instead of `` @bot.event`` inside the cog

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up fixing this by rewriting the cog so it ends in:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print('music.py online.')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

and at the bottom, of the main file:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print('testcog.py online.')
```